# Other word for self-morphing

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

Consider a robot that can draw a shape.

Now let's say that this robot can both **extend** and **redraw** the shape, such that:

- The shape becomes larger
- The current shape changes

Is there a word that can accurately describe this phenomenon?

Words I'm currently thinking of but don't quite capture both the *extend* and *redraw* properties: *self-morphing*, *self-modifying*, *self-extending*, *procedural (?)*

### Edit

The word should be closely related to the fact that this *entity* can grow by itself, without external interference.

### Edit 2

I've learned my lesson: don't try to find the word to something without explaining the entire context. I apologize for this. Here is the full context of the word:

> Let's say there is a model that tries to create Artificial Intelligence (AI). This model learns on-the-go and changes itself accordingly. Therefore, the AI brain can both *change* and *grow*. Strictly speaking, the rules according to which the AI changes its model are fixed and predetermined. The model itself is not. This implies that if data (or input) arrives, the model changes such that if subsequent data arrives, the model handles the data differently. I'm trying to describe the separation between models with a predetermined structure and models that have the explained varying structure (preferably in one word). It is important to note that not just the internal properties of the varying model changes (such as its estimates), but that the model can actually create (or *grow*) completely new areas.

Comment: But the robot itself isn't changing shape, so why do you want ***self-*** ?

Comment: *Self-morphing* would indicate that the robot itself is the shape, and that the robot can change its own shape and size.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did a poor job explaining myself: the robot is nothing more but an algorithm that draws a shape. The algorithm doesn't change but the shape does. All that we observe is the shape.

Comment: *shapeshifter*?

Comment: *Auto-adaptative renderer* ?

Comment: As viewed from an entity that has no knowledge of the robot and can only see the shape:  The shape simply ***morphs*** into a new shape.  If we know about the robot we can say that the robot *morphs* the shape. If we understand the algorithm being used to morph the shape we could say that the algorithm has a feedback loop that includes the shape itself.

Comment: @Jim That is indeed a very accurate analysis of the situation. It's the latter: we understand the algorithm changes the shape. I'm trying to express "*has a feedback loop*" in one word :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the algorithm assesses the situation and takes into account its prior successes and failures, if it has access to history (pseudo-memory) and a way to assess the efficacy or suitability of its prior attempts, it could be called **adaptive** or **heuristic**.

Comment: Perfect! Simple but elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- If the robot changes its own shape, you are looking for **"self reconfiguration"**.  These robots are **"self-reconfigurable"**.

> [**Modular self-reconfigurable robots**](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~modlab/publications/SPIE99final.pdf) consist of large numbers (hundreds or thousands) of identical modules that possess the
>   ability to reconfigure into different shapes as required by the task at hand. For example, such a robot could start out as a
>   snake to traverse a narrow pipe, then re-assemble itself into a six-legged spider to move over uneven terrain, growing a pair
>   of arms to pick up and manipulate an object at the same time.

- If the robot changes the shape of a drawing or sketch, you can say it **reshapes** what it has drawn.

Comment: that is close! However, I would like the word to express the *increasing* property too. Instead of robot, you could also think of an *algorithm* that draws the shape.

Comment: @Jean-Paul  I'm afraid there isn't a single word for that.  Self-reconfiguration is used for any property, both increasing and decreasing.

Comment: @Jean-Paul: The algorithm must either accept new inputs for the shape/size, or have some sort of value generator function.  It it accepts new inputs, the algorithm itself isn't changing. If it generates new inputs, the algorithm isn't changing either.

Comment: @TimRomano I guess you are right. The algorithm doesn't change but the shape does. Thing is, the shape sort of *defines* the functionality of the algorithm. If the shape changes, the algorithm changes too. Indeed, it does this only upon receiving new input.

Comment: The algorithm *recognizes* something and reconfigures itself accordingly?

Comment: Or the shape and its size are inputs?

Comment: @TimRomano The first: it *recognizes* something and reconfigures accordingly. See my clarifying edit.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the entity can *grow*, which sounds a lot like **evolution.** Considering that it evolves without outside stimuli, I suggest **[self-evolution](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-evolution);** per *Merriam Webster:*

> development by inherent quality or power

Comment: This is a good one! Thank you! I'll leave the question open for now to see if someone replies with other (maybe even more?) relevant words.

Comment: @Jean-Paul that's cool :)